# Difference between `Ctrl + A` and `Ctrl + Click`?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I am novice to photoshop and working on converting *PSD* to * HTML*.

I learned that you can select a layer and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, and copy-paste to **create a new image equal to the size of layer**.

I also learned that you can copy by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>left mouse click</kbd>, and copy-paste.

However I noticed that the second method is not good for copying layers with opacity. What is the difference between these two methods of copying layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference just in selection method.. at first case you select the whole artboard, at the second you select just a object on a layer (some transparency can be dropped due threshold).

The second way is good to get selection exactly like an object. It is handy in many cases. And not so when you want have just a full copy.

Btw, you can consider <kbd>Ctrl / Option</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> as well. It makes full duplicate of a layer.